# How many circles of radius r fit in a single bigger circle of radius R?

Tags: geometry, circles, packing-problem, combinatorial-geometry

Is there any formula to calculate how many circles of radius r fit in a single bigger circle of radius R?

Comment: [circle packing in a circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle) or in general [circle packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) is known to be a hard problem. Only a few solutions is known. You exercise must be asking something more specific or it will be impossible for high school to solve.

Comment: And with advanced math? Is it possible?

Comment: As I have said, only few solutions are known. Even with advanced math, no one in the world know the full answer for arbitrary $r$ and $R$. What is the exact statement of your exercise? Does it just ask you for a qualitative description of the tightest arrangement? or to give an estimate/a lower bound/an upper bound for the numbers you can fit in the bigger circle? or simply something else.

Comment: There is the obvious upper bound of $\left(\frac{R}{r}\right)^2$ but even rounding that down to the nearest integer will rarely give you the correct maximum number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a very complicated and investigated problem, usually formulated in the form: given a natural number $n$, which is the smallest  radius $R=R(n)$ of the disk containing $n$ non-overlapping unit disks (that is, disks of radius 1). You can see [results for small $n$ ($\le 20$) at Packing Center by Erich Friedman](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirincir/). For large $n$ ($\gg 10$) it is practically impossible to obtain tight lower bounds for $R(n)$ and upper bounds are found by computers, trying to find tighter and more tighter packings. I can share with you some articles and a program Pack 1.0 related with this problem. I upload them when my file sharing website will work.

Comment: The uploaded files are [here](http://webfile.ru/6686034).